# joint PDF for two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint PDF $f(x,y)=\frac{4}{3}(1-xy)$, $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$.

1) find $P(X<Y)$.

2). Find the expectation of $X.$

For problem 1):

$P(X<Y)=P((X,Y) \in A)$, where $A=\{(x,y):x<y\}$,

\begin{align}  P(X<Y)= {} & \iint_A f(x,y) \,dx\,dy \\ = {} &\iint_{x<y} f(x,y) \,dx\,dy \\
= {} & \int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{4}{3}(1-xy) \, dx \, dy \\
= {} & \int_0^1 \left[ \frac{4}{3} x- \frac{2}{3} x^2 y \right]^{x=y}_x = 0 \, dy \\
= {} & \int_0^1 \left( \frac{4}{3}y-\frac{2}{3}y^3 \right) \, dy \\ = {} & \frac{1}{2} \end{align}

> Question 1: why we are treating y as from 0 to y while x from 0 to 1? Can we switch around, let y from 0 to 1 while x as 0 to x?

2). We can compute the expectation of X in two ways, either by marginal PDF or by joint PDF.

> Question 2: I was told that unlike the discrete type, the continuous type need not have a joint PDF. But why can we compute using joint PDF in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: why we are treating x as from 0 to y while y from 0 to 1? Can we switch around, let x from 0 to 1 while y as 0 to x?

The domain of integration is the intersection of $A$ and the support, which can be expressed in several equivalent ways. $$\begin{align}&\quad~\{\langle x,y\rangle: (0<x<1)\wedge (0<y<1)\wedge (x<y)\}\\&=\{\langle x,y\rangle: (0<x<y<1)\}\\&=\{\langle x,y\rangle: (0<y<1)\wedge (0<x<y)\}\\&=\{\langle x,y\rangle: (0<x<1)\wedge (x<y<1)\}\end{align}$$

So yes.$$\int_0^1\int_0^y\tfrac 43(1-xy)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y~=~\int_0^1\int_x^1\tfrac 43(1-xy)~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d x$$

[See also: [Fubini's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FubiniTheorem.html)]

> Question 2: I was told that unlike the discrete type, the continuous type need not have a joint PDF. But why can we compute using joint PDF in here?

Because you *do* have the joint PDF for *this* particular problem.   It exists and you know what it is.   Not only *may* you use it, it is infact the only thing that you *can* use.

(You need to use it to *find* the marginal and conditional pdf *before* you can use them.   Conserve energy; don't do unnecessary work.)

---

PS: I would also add that because of symmetry in the pdf, you did not need to *integrate*.   Clearly $\mathsf P(X<Y)=\mathsf P(Y<X)$.

Answer (score 2):

> why we are treating $y$ as from $0$ to $y$ while $x$ from $0$ to $1$?

That is NOT being done:
$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^y \frac{4}{3}(1-xy) \, dx\right) \, dy 
$$
In the iterated integral above, $x$ goes from $0$ to $y.$

It can also be written like this:
$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_x^1 \frac 4 3 (1-xy)\, dy \right) \,dx
$$
In this case, $y$ goes from $x$ to $1.$

You have:

$$0\le x \le y \le 1.$$

That's the same as saying
\begin{align}
& 0 \le x \le 1 \\
\text{ and } & x\le y \le 1 \\[10pt]
\text{or } \\[10pt]
& 0 \le y \le 1 \\
\text{and } & 0\le x\le y. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

1. Note that we are integrating $y$ from $0$ to $1$ and $x$ from $0$ to $y$.
2. The joint pdf is given, so it exists and we can use it.